# Persisting test data across apps

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

My Django site has two apps — `Authors` and `Books`. My `Books` app has a model which has a foreign key to a model in `Authors`. I have some tests for the `Authors` app which tests all my models and managers and this works fine. However, my app `Books` require some data from the `Authors` app in order to function.

Can I specify the order in which my tests are run and make the generated test data from app `Authors` persist so that I can test my `Books` app whithout having to copy over the test which generate data from the `Authors` app.

I might be doing this all wrong. Am I?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures) containing the test data you need. You can then load the same data for both your `Authors` and `Books` tests.

For details, see [docs on Testcase.fixures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase.fixtures) and [Introduction to Python/Django tests: Fixtures](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/nov/5/introduction-pythondjango-testing-fixtures/).

Comment: I think fixtures work fine for simple unit tests but I don't think it can serve my purpose when I'm writing a big integration test. I'm making requests to my application using the request module and then checking whether the correct data has been entered into the DB, checking whether the form does validate everything, etc. So it's not really a simple test of testing just the Model or the Manager but it tests everything from the URL configuration, the Views, the Forms, the Managers and the Models i.e the whole stack. Hopefully I have been explicit enough. Thanks Shawn.